# How do I run a cluster analysis on customer store visit data to identify clusters that consist of both location and time?

Tags: r, clustering, business-intelligence

I have data from customer visits to a number of different stores over the course of a few months. In one column I have the time/date of the visit, in another the location of the visit, and in other columns other variables (amount spent during the visit, how many items purchased, what type of items were purchased, etc.). I'm looking to identify different clusters from this data that consist of both location and time information - for example, Saturday afternoon may be one cluster, Christmas holiday another, etc. What is the best way to do this kind of analysis in R?

Comment: Better to ask without asking for R-code. 
This is not an R-coding site.

Comment: You need to be precise about what a "good" cluster is. Otherwise, random partitions are a possible solution. You absolutely need to formalize this.

Comment: I'm not asking for code. There are many different techniques and would be grateful for advice on what to use in this scenario when I don't know how many clusters to expect and have the above-mentioned variables.